# Creating new column with apply() two times leads to overwritten new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written some pandas code that is equivalent to this toy example:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'product': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'sold_for': [5000, 4500, 10000, 8000]})

def product0_makes_profit(row, product0_cost):
    return row['sold_for'] > product0_cost

def product1_makes_profit(row, product1_cost):
    return row['sold_for'] > product1_cost

df_test['made_profit'] = df_test[df_test['product']==0].apply(product0_makes_profit, args=[4000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
df_test['made_profit'] = df_test[df_test['product']==1].apply(product1_makes_profit, args=[9000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
df_test
```

I get the following result:

```
    product sold_for    made_profit
0   0       5000        NaN
1   0       4500        NaN
2   1       10000       True
3   1       8000        False
```

I would expect that column 'made_profit' is True for row 0 and 1, instead of NaN, but apparently the second apply() overwrites the made_profit column, made by the first apply().

How can I get the column I expect? I *don't* want to make a column 'product0_made_profit' with the first apply() and a column 'product1_made_profit' with the second apply(), so I can merge both columns into the one 'made_profit' column that I want to obtain, since in my real code, I have a lot of different values in the product column (meaning lots of different functions to apply).

**EDIT**

I made my toy example too simple, I actually create two new columns:

```
def product0_makes_profit(row, product0_cost):
    return [row['sold_for'] > product0_cost, row['sold_for'] - product0_cost]

def product1_makes_profit(row, product1_cost):
    return [row['sold_for'] > product1_cost, row['sold_for'] - product1_cost]
```

Using the current answer, I made this:

```
is_prod0 = (df_test['product']==0)
df_test.loc[is_prod0, ['made_profit', 'profit_amount']] = df_test[is_prod0].apply(product0_makes_profit, args=[4000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
is_prod1 = (df_test['product']==1)
df_test.loc[is_profd1, ['made_profit', 'profit_amount']] = df_test[is_prod1].apply(product1_makes_profit, args=[9000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
print(df_test)
```

But that gives me the following error (on the first use of .loc):

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['made_profit', 'profit_amount'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

I *can* make it work with the following code:

```
is_prod0 = (df_test['product']==0)
newdf = df_test[is_prod0].apply(product0_makes_profit, args=[4000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
is_prod1 = (df_test['product']==1)
newerdf = df_test[is_prod1].apply(product1_makes_profit, args=[9000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
newcols = pd.concat([newdf, newerdf])
newcols.columns = ['was_profit_made', 'profit_amount']
df_test.join(newcols)
```

However, this involves concat() and join() and as said above, gets a little tedious on the real-life code (but feasible by building a loop over all product values) - maybe there is an elegant solution for multiple columns too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need assign to filtered rows with same condition with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), so processes only rows if conditions is `True`:

```
m1 = df_test['product']==0
m2 = df_test['product']==1
df_test.loc[m1, 'made_profit'] = df_test[m1].apply(product0_makes_profit, args=[4000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
df_test.loc[m2, 'made_profit'] = df_test[m2].apply(product1_makes_profit, args=[9000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
print (df_test)
   product  sold_for  made_profit
0        0      5000         True
1        0      4500         True
2        1     10000         True
3        1      8000        False
```

EDIT:

If return multiple values from `function` need return `Series` with index by new columns names, also is necessary create new columns filled some default value (e.g. `NaN`) before `loc`:

```
cols = ['made_profit', 'profit_amount']
def product0_makes_profit(row, product0_cost):
    return pd.Series([row['sold_for'] > product0_cost, row['sold_for'] - product0_cost], index=cols)

def product1_makes_profit(row, product1_cost):
    return pd.Series([row['sold_for'] > product1_cost, row['sold_for'] - product1_cost], index=cols)

for c in cols:
    df_test[c] = np.nan

is_prod0 = (df_test['product']==0)
df_test.loc[is_prod0, cols] = df_test[is_prod0].apply(product0_makes_profit, args=[4000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
is_prod1 = (df_test['product']==1)
df_test.loc[is_prod1, cols] = df_test[is_prod1].apply(product1_makes_profit, args=[9000], axis=1, result_type="expand")
print(df_test)

   product  sold_for  made_profit  profit_amount
0        0      5000         True         1000.0
1        0      4500         True          500.0
2        1     10000         True         1000.0
3        1      8000        False        -1000.0
```

Comment: Thanks already! But It seems I made my toy example too simple. I actually insert two new columns, and I can't get this to work in that situation. I updated my question.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!